# Firebase getting delay on posting imageURL to DB using storage which is causing my push method to break when trying to add new data to the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm creating an object called testData that contains different attributes. One of these attributes is a Picture attribute where I get the user to upload an image and then I store the image in Firebase using storage. However, when I try to push the data using 
`firebaseRef.push(testData)... => { ... }`
I get this error:

> firebase-storage.js:3476 Uncaught Error: Reference.push failed: first
>   argument contains undefined in property 'Picture'

Below is what my `testData` object looks like:

```js
var testData = {
   "Name" : name,
   "Phone" : phone.value,
   "Picture" : downloadURL,
   "q1": q1.value,
   "q2": q2.value,
   "q3": q3.value
   };
```

But if I wait one second and click the submit button one more time to push the `testData` to `firebase`, it properly executes and everything works. It looks like there is a delay from when the image that is being uploaded gets sent to Firebase Storage and forms the `downloadURL` which I'm saving as a field so that I know which image is associated to which key. Anyone know why I have this wierd bug where the first attempt at saving to firebase doesn't work, and then you wait one second and try again, and then it executes properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way.

```
 uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
       var percentageUploaded = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100; //check if its' 100% then get the download url like below,
          if(percentageUploaded ==100){
            storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
                //here you'll get the download url once the file is uploaded.
                var testData = {
                     "Name" : name,
                     "Phone" : phone.value,
                     "Picture" : url,
                     "q1": q1.value,
                     "q2": q2.value,
                     "q3": q3.value,
                     "Timestamp": firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
                 };
          //then do your push to the firebase
          firebaseRef.push(testData).then((snap) => {
              console.log("pushed to firebase");
           });
              });
         }   

    });
```

[See this jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/80m8L653/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the promise that `.put()` returns

For example:

```
firebase.storage().ref('path').put( /* file */ ).then(
  snapshot => {
    firebase.database()
      .ref('path')
      .set({ 
        name: 'name',
        downloadURL: snapshot.downloadURL,
        // other properties
      })
  },
  error => {
    // Handle potential errors
  }
)
```

This ensures the file has been uploaded before the database is updated

Comment: Hm, try adding another argument to the storage's `.then()`. It should be a function that accepts an `error` parameter. Does that ever run? Also, you might want to move that `window.location.href = "..."` into the second `.then()`, otherwise the page might change before the upload or database update is done.

Comment: That did it! I was navigating away before the database update was happening so it was causing that issue. Thank you so much for your help!!!!